# extract values between delimiters pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas

I have a DF with one column with a string like this: eth 2/2206/114/1/20
I need to extract each value since I'm use a regex. For the first value i use:

`r'eth(.*?)/'` to extract the first value between `eth` and `/`

`r'/(.*?)/'` to extract value `2206`

But, how can extract the next values? I need to ignore the first delimiter '/', is there anyway to ignore the first delimiter to extract value 114 between  the two next slash or how can i get this output?

Comment: Write a single regex matching the string format and then use capturing groups in proper places. Or, try to get all with named capturing groups, like `df['colname'].str.extract(r'^eth\s+(?P<eth>\d+)/(?P<first>\d+)/(?P<second>\d+)/(?P<third>\d+)/(?P<fourth>\d+)$')`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew would a more greedy regex be better here (if the number of / is unknown) something like `(eth)(.*)(!?\s)` then OP could split on the delim and take what items he needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution :

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{"my_col": "eth 2/2206/114/1/20"}])
# remove the 'eth' part and save it in an other column
df['my_col_copy'] = df['my_col'].str.extract(r'eth (.*)')
# split in multiple columns
df[['val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4', 'val5']] = df['my_col_copy'].str.split('/', expand=True)
```

output :

```
my_col               my_col_copy        val1  val2  val3   val4  val5
eth 2/2206/114/1/20  2/2206/114/1/20    2     2206  114    1     20
```

Comment: this is way to lazy, if you have text after `eth` it will capture it _all_

Comment: all the strings have the same length, so this is enough for me to get the data for other operations. after, I drop thats columns. I was blocked when I writte the question, probably the other options are better but this is enough for me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since it is not specified, I will suppose that the number of value to extract is variable.

With that in mind, I'd say a regex is not the most efficient tool to solve your problem because (1) the pattern to match isn't very complex and (2) with a variable numbers of value, it is very difficult - if not impossible - to extract them all in an efficient way.

An easier way to extract these values would be to use the string [split()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm) method (with an added verification using [startswith()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_startswith.htm), to be sure the `eth` prefic is indeed present) on a spliced string, to keep 'eth ' out of the split. Here is a code snippet as an example:

```py
column = 'eth 2/2206/114/1/20'  # Or any other valid values

if column.startswith('eth '):
    values = column[4:].split('/')
else:
    values = None  # Here, manage the invalid case how you prefer

print(values)
```

Results:

```
['2', '2206', '114', '1', '20']
```